# What is the Google Spreadsheet syntax for the HYPERLINK formula to reference another cell that contains a hyperlink rather than a straight url string?

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets, formula

The hyperlink formula works nicely here - the effect is to hyperlink nicely from the image in the cell

```
=HYPERLINK( "http://www.google.com" ; IMAGE( "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" ) )
```

But what if we wanted to reference the hyperlink directly from another cell?

```
=HYPERLINK( "A2" ; IMAGE( "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" ) )
```

I can't quite seem to crack this little baby ;-)

Would provide users with the knowledge and ability to represent thumbnails hyperlinking to their bigger source files in a new window.

I have created a spreadsheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AogxdfOvltKQdDR4c3R2Y0hkdVdVTTFCTWtOVUVaVWc&usp=sharing

Many thanks, Mark

Comment: You need to open the access to the spreadsheet so we can see

Comment: Thanks. Done. Made Public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
=HYPERLINK("A3" ; IMAGE(A3&"/convert?h=225"))
```

to

```
=HYPERLINK(A3 ; IMAGE(A3&"/convert?h=225"))
```

"A3" would be a named reference whereas A3 is a cell

Comment: Genious. Made My Day;-)