# make image clickable in google spreadsheet

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, clickable-image

I try to make clickable an imported image into Google spreadsheet.
When I click it to take me to another website.

I was able to:
- insert the image
- to 'Assign script' to it
- that looks like this:

```
function showMessageBox() {
  Browser.msgBox('You clicked it!');
}
```

When I click the image the above message comes up. However I need a script that I can assign and opens an outside url when image clicked.

Is there such a script available?

Answer (score 6):

These are the two solutions I was able to come up with:

(1) Assign this script to your image and replace the link with your own. It requires one more user click, but it's probably the best you can do. Caja locks down everything output by the HTML Service pretty tight, so things like `window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");` or `window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";` are a no go.

```
function redirectTest(){
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<a href="http://www.example.com">Click Me!</a>')
    .setWidth(100)
    .setHeight(100);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, " ");
}
```

(2) According to [this source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BjnpMxEdbcI) and [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881022/what-is-the-google-spreadsheet-syntax-for-the-hyperlink-formula-to-reference-ano), the following formula should work:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.example.com", IMAGE("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"))
```

I couldn't get it to work in my tests, but the sources aren't that old.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve clickable images with formulas alone. But clickable link appears only after cell selection, not sure if its acceptable in your case.

`=HYPERLINK("http://www.artchive.com/artchive/d/durer/durer_mill.jpg", image("http://www.artchive.com/artchive/d/durer/durer_mill.jpg"))`

[image]

Comment: worked for me thank you ,  But Hyperlinks are not working when you opened it in Mobile browsers(Touch Screeen).