# How to make a clickable image event by using only a script in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

So I want to have a button in my google spreadsheet that will send an email when clicked (using info from the the google spreadsheet). I found  [this in the google apps script guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

[image: screenshot]

This is exactly what I want, but I need to make a lot of such buttons on different spreadsheets, so it's really not feasible to do this manual. Is there a way to do this with a script?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176203/make-image-clickable-in-google-spreadsheet) but no useful answer was given.

Comment: @SandyGood he's not just asking about inserting images but assigning those to a script function, AFAIU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nopes, you cannot do it programmatically. This has already been discussed here: [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5610)

and the google person has made it clear that it is not something that they would support ever.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I think you misread his reply. He says that 'allowing arbitrary add-on functions to be assigned to spreadsheet images' is not something they intend to support, but in the third paragraph he says that programmatically attaching script functions to spreadsheet images could be a possible feature request. Anyways, sad that it's not possible.